# Slow internet connected affects game performance

Tags: internet

When working away from home, I often find myself in the hotel room playing online games.

Mostly, these are MMO's (Mass Multiple Player), which run slowly when the internet connection is <0.5MB/s. I understand this, because there are constant messages and synchronisations between my PC and the server, so as multiple people can play simultaneously.

Why, though, do browser based games which are not multiple player run slowly?

This is not regarding the time it takes for the game to load, but when the game is actually running. I would have thought that the game would only communicate with the server once the game is saved, or scores are submitted.

Edit: One of the games in question is http://www.miniclip.com/games/earn-to-die-2012-part-2/en/#t-h-a-H This takes a while to load (as expected) but it then also runs slowly (<1fps).

Comment: Can you give an example or two of what games you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you are behind a firewall, monitoring software, or filtering of some kind.  Many hotels monitor their guests' internet usage which slows down the speeds.  Really no way around this unless you connect to someone near the hotel that doesn't monitor so heavily.

Comment: I can understand why this would effect the speed of the whole page loading, but why would this effect the game once it is running? I would imagine that when I go to a webpage with a game, the files required to run the game are moved to my PC (cache?) so it can be run. It seems to me like the game requires an active internet connection to run. My question is why?

Comment: Well I have no idea which game you are playing but many are transfering data back and forth with the site even if it may seem like its not. Which games?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Don't know why I am getting a thumbs down since it is a valid reason... I still think this is what is happening for your game